# Prove if $AB=BA $ and $BC=CB$ then $AC=CA$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

> $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ denote the group of two by two matrices with non-zero determinant. Let $A,B,C\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $A,B,C\neq aI$ where I is the identity of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ . Prove if $AB=BA $ and $BC=CB$ then $AC=CA$.

I try to proof this just use the properties of a group, but it seems not enough. There need to be some properties of matrices. More generally, does this property (if a commutes with b and b commutes with c,then a commutes with c).

Comment: You definitely need to use the structure of this particular group. For example in $S_5$, the transposition $ (1\; 2) $ commutes both with $(3\; 4)$ and $(3\; 5)$ but they do not commute.

Comment: This will help : https://martin-thoma.com/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative/#simultaneous-diagonalization